# Fetch chosen options attribute with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, select

So i have several `selects` with several `options`.
Now i'd like to fetch the chosen values and attributes.

**HTML**

```
<select class="namnTillagg">
  <option value="+fotpl" data-enhet="st">+fotpl</option><option value="+toppl" data-enhet="st">+toppl</option><option value="1 svpl" data-enhet="st">1 svpl</option>
</select>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.namnTillagg').each(function(){ 
    var temp = $(this);
    namnTillagg[a] = temp.val();
    a++;
})
```

With this `Jquery` i'm able to fetch all my selected `selects` `value`.
Now i'd like to fetch the arrtibute "data-enhet" from the selected option/value
How can i do this?

**Example Code**

```
$('.namnTillagg').each(function(){ 
    var temp = $(this);
    namnTillagg[a] = temp.val();
    enhetTillagg = $(temp.val(namnTillagg[a]).attr('data-enhet'); //Can i do it something like this?
    a++;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find selected option in current select along with `.data()` to find its data property or `.attr()` to find its data attribute value:

```
temp.find(':selected').data('enhet');
```

You can also use index parameter of `.each()` rather than maintaining different variable `a`:

**Full Snippet:**

```
$('.namnTillagg').each(function(i){ 
 var temp = $(this);
 namnTillagg[i] = temp.val();
 enhetTillagg[i] = temp.find(':selected').data('enhet'); 
})
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much. Plus for (i).